# What one really can do with fractals built from L-systems?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, fractals

For any L-system one can naturally associate a fractal. Why these fractals are (mathematically) useful apart that they are a source of nice pictures?

Answer (score 7):

The original use of L-systems is to model the fractal-like forms that appear in plant growth. Johan Knutzen gives a nice overview with pictures in [Generating Climbing Plants Using L-Systems](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~uffe/xjobb/climbingplants.pdf).

In computer science, L-systems are used to generate the space-filling fractal curve that maps IP addresses to computers ([Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve)).

More recent applications include musical compositions with a self-similar structure, as described by Stellios Manousakis in [Musical L-systems.](http://www.sonology.org/NL/thesis-pdf/Stelios%20Manousakis-Musical%20L-systems.pdf) (This musical rendering of L-sytems has been called [Growing Music.](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/bib/ss/nonstd/eurogp05.pdf))

------ Here is how an L-system fractal [sounds in C minor](https://soundcloud.com/prologomenon/fractal-plant-in-c-minor).

More musical compositions based on L-systems can be found [here.](http://prologomenon.wordpress.com/category/xenakis/)

Comment: I find it amazing that Xenakis used L-systems in his work. Well, after all he knew Maths very well

Answer (score 6):

The [Wikipedia page for L-systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) links to the [Thue-Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prouhet-Thue-Morse_system) for which there are a large number of applications.  In particular it can be interpreted as the sequence of distances between atoms in a 1D quasicrystal.  Hence I suppose you might think about the work on substitution tilings and higher dimensional quasicrystals as an application of similar ideas.

Thinking even more broadly, [the recent work by Borrelli, Jabrane, Lazarus and Thibert](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~borrelli/Hevea/Presse/index-en.html) on implementing convex integration for a $C^1$ embedding of a flat torus in $R^3$ uses explicitly an L-system-like rewriting process to add corrugations.